# Factory fails when invoked in definition of another factory

Tags: database, django, unit-testing, factory, django-testing

**SOLVED**: The example here was not accurate and didn't show the problem. The solution is in the answer I've given below.

---

How can I **import a factory** from a different app's unit test module, and use it to create instances in this test module?

I have a Django project with several apps. The unit tests are using [Factory Boy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/factory_boy/) to create instances of the models for testing. (The models are managed by [South](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/South), and the settings have `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` as advised.)

In app `bar`'s unit tests, I want to create test instances of `Foo`, a model defined in app `foo`.

App `foo`'s unit test module already has a factory `FooFactory`, which is the factory I want to use:

```python
# foo/tests.py

import factory
…

from . import models

class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Foo

    spam = 0
    …
```

So in `bar`, the app I'm now writing tests for, I need that `FooFactory`. I try to import and use it:

```python
# bar/tests.py

import factory
…

from . import models
from foo.tests import FooFactory

class BarFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Bar

    foo = factory.SubFactory(FooFactory)
    …

class BarTest(TestCase):
    """ Test cases for ‘Bar’ model. """

    def test_frobnicates_to_spanguloid(self):
        """ The instance should frobnicate to a spanguloid. """
        test_foo = FooFactory(code=34)
        test_bar = BarFactory(foo=test_foo)
```

But the test cases fail with `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: foo_foo` trying to create an instance of `foo.Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (not evidenced in the simplified example) was an attempt to **call the factory in the definition of another factory**:

```python
class BarFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Bar

    spam = FooFactory(code=34)
```

That fails with `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: foo_foo`, because the call is made when Django's test runner is importing the unit test module. At that point, none of the models are in the database.

Instead, any calls to the factories must **wait until the tests are run**, not when the classes are defined. In this case:

```python
class BarFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Bar

    spam = factory.SubFactory(FooFactory)
    …

class BarTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """ Set up test fixtures. """
        self.test_foo = FooFactory(code=34)

    def test_frobnicates_to_spanguloid(self):
        """ The instance should frobnicate to a spanguloid. """
        test_bar = BarFactory(foo=self.test_foo)
```